# How to see loss vs epoch graph on tensorboard while keras model gets trained?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, loss-function

I have a 2 layer keras Sequential model with 2 Dense layers for performing regression.
My sequential model is as follows:

```
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=7))
  model.add(Dense(1))
  model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='rmsprop')
```

I have initialized tensorboard (keras.callbacks.Tensorboard) and have passed it to the model.fit method as a callback.

```
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/', histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

On launching tensorboard, I can see the computational graph but I also want to visualise the loss decreasing with epochs while training, on Tensorboard. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: It should log those values and Tensorboard updates live while training. Have you tried just launching it while training?

Comment: Solved! I was running tensorflow 1.0.1. I had to reinstall tensorflow and upgrade to 1.8.0. Then it worked. Thanks for your comment @nuric!